# How to return only the values that exist?

Tags: python, return

I am parsing #data1 and #data2 from a ton of files. Some files don't have both though so when I return data1,data2 it results in:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data2' referenced before assignment
```

I've looked several other questions and I thought something like try/except looked promising but I don't want it to throw an error if one of the values doesn't exist.

I tried various if statements, but get the same UboundLocalError.

```
if data1 and data2:
    return data1, data2
```

Is there a simple way to check that the value exists before trying to return it?

```
data1, data2 = parse_file(filename)

def parse_file(sample):
    for line in open(sample, 'r'):
        if line.startswith('#data1'):
            #Clean up the value
            data1 = line.strip().split('=')[-1]

        elif line.startswith('#data2'):
            #Clean up the value 
            data2 = line.strip().split('=')[-1]

        #Go to next line if it doesn't have either
        else: continue

    return data1, data2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data1` and `data2` are only defined depending on what your line starts with. If your line never started with `'#data2'`, `data2` never got defined.

You can just initialize them both to be `None`s to get rid of your error:

```
def parse_file(sample):
    for line in open(sample, 'r'):
        data1, data2 = None, None # Initialize them here if you want them reset for every iteration
        # do stuff
```